# Remove bullets from <ul>?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an incredibly simple html structure like below:

```
<ul id="menu" ng-show="showMenu">
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">a</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.msn.com" target="_blank">b</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body{
  background:#f2f2f0;
  padding:15px;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style:none !important;
}
#menu li a{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

The `ul` still shows bullets even though I set `list-style` to none. When I remove the `#menu`, it works as desired. Why is this happening? `#menu` is the id of the `ul`, it should apply to the menu element. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#menu ul` is trying to target a `ul` that is a descendant of `#menu`. This is incorrect, since in your case they are the same element. `ul#menu` would be correct.

Comment: `ul that is the child of #menu` Not necessarily, but a descendant.

Comment: Super simple. Sorry, it's been a while since i've made a web page :)

Comment: @HashemQolami - great point, I will edit my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 5):

You are targeting a non-existing element (a `<ul>` that is a child of an element with `id="menu"`.  The element you want to target is an `<li>` that is a child of an element with `id="menu"` like this:

```
#menu li{
    list-style:none; //you can remove !important
}
```

Another option is to create a menu class `no-bullet`.

`<ul id="menu" class="no-bullet" ng-show="showMenu">` and use the same CSS as above, except replace `#menu li` with `.no-bullet`.

Comment: Just `#menu` alone should work, the `<li>`s inherit this property from the `<ul>`.

Comment: I noticed that as well, there are lots of potential ways of doing this, but I prefer specificity since the id `#menu` could be used elsewhere.  However I updated my answer to indicate the alternative of using a simpler identifier.

Comment: IDs are unique, and should not be re-used under any circumstances.

Comment: If the stylesheet is loaded on many pages there might be multiple elements with `id="menu"`

Comment: Well, it's generally good practice to make IDs unique throughout the website, especially for common elements like navigaton.

Comment: Ok but in reality as a site grows an id may get re-used, especially if it's a generic one like `menu`, for that reason I suggested creating a new class called `no-bullet`.